# Displaying random JSON data

Tags: json

I have this code that displays JSON data. How could this code be remade to display random JSON data every 30 seconds?

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var data= response.data;

        var output = '';
       for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){ 
         output += ''+data[0].data1+''+data[0].data2+'<br/>';
       }
        document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = output;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "url.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Here is an example of JSON

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data":"John",
      "data2": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "data":"Nick",
      "data2": "Doe"
    },
  ]
}
```

How would it be best to use with setInterval, so that one minute "John Doe" is displayed, and other "Nick Doe"?

Comment: Hint: [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: @tadman I thought of that but I have no idea how to use it in this way.
Could it be used if I use only JQuery to display JSON?

Comment: Hint: It can call any function on a regular schedule. Put this in a function. Call it.

Comment: @tadman You are really confusing me now.. :/

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ yourFunction(); }, 30000);` Put your code in the function and call it like this.

Comment: @BhavikPatel Hm okay, I think I get it, but my current requests only takes a specific JSON data?

Comment: do you have different `json` 's ? If yes then just change your `url` on every cakk. Also your  `output += ''+data[0].data1+''+data[0].data2+'<br/>'; ` will always print your first object because of `data[0]`

Comment: @BhavikPatel Ihave one JSON file with multiple elements.
Yes, data[0] displays first element, but I do not know how to display other elements with setInterval.
First minute is one element, second minute is other element.

Comment: @BhavikPatel I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `setInterval` to call your logic every 30secs. Set `index=0` initially and reset when it equals to your json's length.

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var data= response.data;

        var output = '';
        var index = 0; // set your index
     setInterval(function(){
        if (index == data.length){
            index= 0; // reset when equals json's length
        }
        output = ''+data[index].data1+''+data[index].data2+'<br/>';
        document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = output;
        index++; // move to next element
     },30000);

      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "url.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```